# Registering a different generic type as scanned

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I try to register a generic type `Repository<T>` with the interface `IRepository<T>` where `T` is `IEntity`.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
       .Where(t => typeof(IEntity).IsAssignableFrom(t))
       .WithMetadata("Type", (t) => t)
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

The question is now how to register for each `IEntity` found my class

```
Repository<T>: IRepository<T> where T: IEntity
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to register the entities, you only have to register the repository. Autofac have excellent support for generics, both open and closed types. From the [OpenGenerics](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OpenGenerics) documentation, register the open generic type of your repository:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
    .As(typeof(IRepository<>));
```

You can now resolve closed repository types like this:

```
var userRepo = container.Resolve<IRepository<User>>();
```